# React Context API / Bind function in context file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I am trying to use the context api. I'm getting an error TypeError: 'this.props.fetchWeather is not a function' when I submit the form.

My WeatherContext file has a WeatherProvider & WeatherConsumer. My state and a fetchWeather function are this file. When I log what is being passed to the value fetchWeather logs as undefined.

```
{term: "", forecast: Array(0), fetchWeather: undefined}
```

My question is how do I define the fetchWeather function within the WeatherContext? I tried binding it. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

This question has been updated to reflect changes I made ...

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

import { WeatherProvider, WeatherContext } from 
'./context/WeatherContext'

ReactDOM.render(
     <WeatherProvider>
        <WeatherContext.Consumer>
            {({ term, forecast, fetchWeather }) => 
                 <App term={ term } 
                      forecast={ forecast } 
                      fetchWeather={ fetchWeather }  />
            }
        </WeatherContext.Consumer>
     </WeatherProvider>, 
     document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

src/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchForm from './components/Search/Search_Form'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <SearchForm {...this.props}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

src/context/WeatherContext

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'lodash'

export const WeatherContext = React.createContext();

export class WeatherProvider extends React.Component {

    state = {
        context: {
            input: '',
            forecast: [],
            fetchWeather: this.fetchWeather
        }
    }

     fetchWeather = (term) => {
        let QUERY = term
        const KEY = `key`
        let URL = `http://url.com/q=${QUERY}&appid=${KEY}`

        axios.get(URL)
        .then( res => {
          // do something ...
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <WeatherContext.Provider 
            value={{ ...this.state.context }} >
                { this.props.children }
            </WeatherContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

src/components/Search/index

```
import React from 'react'
import { WeatherContext } from '../../context/WeatherContext'
import SearchForm from './Search_Form'

export default (props) => (
    <WeatherContext.Consumer>
        {
            ({fetchWeather}) => 
            <SearchForm {...props} fetchWeather={fetchWeather} />
        }
    </WeatherContext.Consumer>
)
```

src/components/Search/Search_Form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SearchForm extends Component {
    handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let term = this.input.value
        this.props.fetchWeather(term)
    }

    handleClear =(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            input: ''
        }) 
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
         <div>
             <form className="form" onSubmit={ this.handleFormSubmit }>
                <input type='text'
                    placeholder='Enter a US City'
                    ref={input => { this.input = input }}/>
                <button type="submit"> Search </button>        
                <button onClick={ this.handleClear }> x </button>
             </form>
         </div>

        )
     }
}


 export default SearchForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the App component, you are not passing the props to the SearchForm component and since you have wrapped the SearchForm with With `WeatherContext` in `components/Search/index.js` which you aren't using in App.js, the fetchWeather prop SearchForm is undefined. You need to use SearchForm in App.js from `components/Search/index.js` like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchForm from './components/Search/index.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <SearchForm />
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

or

pass the props down from App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchForm from './components/Search/Search_Form'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <SearchForm {...this.props}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: So App is receiving props. This is what console.logs {term: "", forecast: Array(0), fetchWeather: undefined} SearchForm is what is not receiving props

Comment: So dumb, How did I miss that? Props are now passing to the SearchForm. Thank you. Forecast is still undefined though. I'm guessing it's the source of the this.props.forecast(term) is not a function error. If the WeatherContext used a constructor that error would usually be a binding issue. How do I properly define fetchWeather inside the WeatherContext?

Comment: @TYPOI, Not sure where exactly are you getting the error, but you must take into account that in SearchForm you are only passing fetchWeather from context and not forecase and term

Comment: fetchWeather is undefined from in the WeatherContext. I was only passing the fetchWeather function because I didn't need the forecast here and the term is already is being passed in. I changed it to 
{ ({ ...props }) =>  <SearchForm {...props}/> } in the Search/index file but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the undefined fetchWeather issue. The answer was to take the fetchWeather function out of the state and put it inside a constructor in the WeatherProvider class. Then bind it. I was tired...